# Infer and restrict types for values of a Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am trying to create a type for a function parameter that restricts its Record values based on a `type` string and an optional `multiple` boolean:
e.g.

```js
useQuery({
  a: {
    ref: ref(''), // ref is a string
    type: 'string',
  },
  b: {
    whitelist: [1, 2, 3], // whitelist is always optional and an array of the type
    ref: ref([1, 2, 3]), // ref is a number array
    type: 'number',
    multiple: true,
  },
});
```

So a simple approach would be to do something like the following, but it doesn't work completely as the optional multiple boolean does not correctly restrict the ref type.

```js
type DumbType = {
      whitelist?: string[];
      ref: Ref<string>;
      type: 'string';
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: string[];
      ref: Ref<string[]>;
      type: 'string';
      multiple: true;
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: number[];
      ref: Ref<number>;
      type: 'number';
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: number[];
      ref: Ref<number[]>;
      type: 'number';
      multiple: true;
    }
 | e.g.

useQuery({
 type: 'string',
 ref: ref(), // ref is inferred with string | string[] - without multiple: true
})
```

I am trying to solve it using Mapped Types, but I am stuck with the following.

`QueryOptions` itself seems to work fine, but `UseQueryOptions` is unable to infer the generics of the Record values.

```js
type Primitives = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean';

export type UseQueryOptions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: QueryOptions<T[K]['type'], T[K]['multiple']>; // <= error
};

export type QueryOptions<T extends Primitives, M extends boolean | undefined> = {
  whitelist?: StringTypeToType<T, true>;
  ref: Ref<StringTypeToType<T, M>>;
  type: T;
  multiple?: M;
};

export type StringTypeToType<P extends Primitives, M extends boolean | undefined> = P extends 'string'
  ? ArrayWhenMultiple<M, string>
  : P extends 'number'
  ? ArrayWhenMultiple<M, number>
  : P extends 'boolean'
  ? ArrayWhenMultiple<M, boolean>
  : never;

export type ArrayWhenMultiple<M extends boolean | undefined, T = any> = M extends true ? T[] : T;

export type TypeToRefType<P extends Primitives, M extends boolean> = Ref<StringTypeToType<P, M>>;

export const useQuery = <P extends Primitives, m extends boolean | undefined>(options: QueryOptions<P, M>) => {};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAKgPigXisqB6XUokUYANgIYDGEAFgPakAmEATgFCV0B2AzsFCwSYoKYeS4hUACjAAubAEp5cJGkzowAbjZsi0AAosAlgFsjwIwDcIPYQHI+xrgHM7UAD5Q7XAK4mARqxunnb+dAwQ4nbabBAAHmB0LPx6UACqPBAAij6sIADyYBbcPCjoWADebFA1UADaANJQRlxQANYQIHTw2AC68jl5hcW8KI29dXZ6dr0ANNjjkyY+pBZkEDOomngEiFisLElsAL4x8YnJhODQgywFRUYlovHAEFyMtoam5lY28wCyUBebw+UDCEXEHigPneCBaEEY5SgVVqUAA7jRzBBSEY+AB+eQAZWATmcyGuyDo5MgKHmJNyW2qtUE8GUCEQxNJ1IglO5tKg-1QjNRenkyG0qOWqyM6wJAu0px05ySKWuUE5LTJFKp10Q+iBcVe70+xjMFmsPABBqNoPBpEirU8MOY8HhiOE+uBxq8jk1diZNTxUAAgiwWOQQAB1Ghvf4rNb2xD-ea+lyoANQeSew0g2zePyBFj+1FB0PhqMxrhx6XrJPzXwBVjp1FZ625rx2h3F2qlsMR6Ox+MyxPJsHhe3iZu1eRcCDWFhnBIqq7EMv9yvVhMQJNt72dyFO2Gu2eMeY4LDiSTCQFe0H06BB5B1XqZ7CLi6q4jcykqPnZm0mt85p-AKu62uODpIioHIkpq346jS+gAkK77LpwvD8D4mS3CAwiiBeEjSHQDwlPIGTZLkdzDI8oxoAo6jIlAipsFhFF5FIKK1OQ8icaiNQsvILJSHYdgKPM+BQDw9ArIwYLQCyiCps4U58SuEDyA4sEuHYswZscumov4PEZqiAkCAgUh1AAjPMABM8wAMy9GJOySdJTBybA7INoWz4qXxopeD5QQGapUBSlu8j3qFNT6ScCgxEAA)

Comment: what are `Ref` and `ref()`?

Comment: Types from vue, you can treat them as identity type and function

Answer (score 1):

The union approach should be preferred for simplicity's sake. But there is some ambiguity in your definition which leads to the issues. The compiler can not properly discriminate the union, as the `multiple` property is only present in some constituents. In a structural type system, something like

```
{
   ref: ref("abc"),
   type: 'string',
   multiple: true
}
```

would not break the contract of your current union type as excess properties are mostly allowed.

We should remove this ambiguity by handling the `multiple` property for each constituent. This can be done by either forbidding the property from being set with `multiple?: undefined` or by typing it to be either *not set* or `false` if the `ref` type is `Ref<string[]>` or `Ref<number[]>`. I think allowing `false` values makes sense, so here is how that would look like:

```
type DumbType = {
      whitelist?: string[];
      ref: Ref<string>;
      type: 'string';
      multiple?: false
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: string[];
      ref: Ref<string[]>;
      type: 'string';
      multiple: true;
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: number[];
      ref: Ref<number>;
      type: 'number';
       multiple?: false
    }
  | {
      whitelist?: number[];
      ref: Ref<number[]>;
      type: 'number';
      multiple: true;
    }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAICVoDMA8AVAfLAvLNwBjAewDsBnUWAJ2R1nQBoMAKAQyoHMAuPAShyzsOYKHAAiAVwC2AIzSi6Ab2CxVagO4ALAJahoAG20UA-DwpVtJDgG0AugG4Va1TSQ9Eqc5Y4ZHz1RAwPADkXlbBfv5SEvqg2pD60KawSKz6ZNBOqgC+TgA+sMr+sFq6BkagyWE2Dllqru7IKNV2vnUBoiHVEe2w0bHxiTygVBLQkTn5hb2leoYmPCTSMtBUdhP1yI2oS7KrbcWB0CG7K1Q9xX0xcQlJPKnpmc65qgVF-rPlC7Cnq+u9DQQTV+a1sB38RxOy1WFyi10Gx1gIzGG1ywCQEhIBDipFgEgyAEUxlRwGxOI1iFQACbNEbeBiwSSyeQwDD8RRo-HQImrUnvVg8d4uLbUZDMYLBXgMgD00tFSFgRlgrFg1TqkNgoTp4QYTmyutUMkFdU+81APGsAEYGQAmBkAZlsMrlpoqirIyv06lY4A9REgOJIaWVJCpIeVVCoPtgRAVoE0cCOdUBrmYVttDtsUtgsvl7uVP2hVAjUfA6s6mpBwQNan6NyGSNG0Br+qcBGNzg1WosOuTItTACIB9nc6585YkKsaGH1LpNKrtRxYAUWrZYABaEpzogSSh1hHDJt64DZXj2IA)

Comment: Would it be possible to do with mapped type? I understand that this approach is simpler and will use it. But I would like to improve my understanding of typescript, hence I would like to know how it would work with mapped types.

Comment: I am not really sure if its possible. You want to infer the whole object as `T`, but you also want to validate it using a mapped type. There is no easy way to do both things at once, only hacky solutions. I am not ruling out that someone could find a solution though.